# Stochastic dominance question

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$ be a non-negative random variable such that $\mathbb{E}X=a$ and $\mathbb{P}(X=a) < 1$. Let us define 
$Y=X-\varepsilon$, when $X>a$ and $Y=X$, when $X\leqslant a$. Here $0<\varepsilon<a$. Can you give a strict proof that $\mathbb{P}(Y \leqslant X)=1$?

Update:
Intuitively it might be stated as evident, however $\mathbb{P}(Y \leqslant X)$ means a joint distribution of vector $(X,Y)$ and I seek to see how that can be calculated out via joint distribution function $\mathbb{P}(X\leqslant x, Y \leqslant y)$.

Comment: Lots of unnecessary hypothesis is probably confusing you. You only need the defintion of $Y$ to draw the conclusion.

Comment: Are you sure that this is what you want to ask. The evidence of the answer combined with the number of conditions make me doubt.

Answer (score 1):

If $Y=X-\epsilon$  when $X>a$ and $Y=X$when $X \leq a$  then $Y\leq X$ at every sample point so $P(Y\leq X)=1$.